# PHP drop menu not sticking

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, sticky

I  asked this question already but have since over hauled the code following the help I got. I am trying to make my php drop menu sticky but it clears to the top menu item every time after the submit button is pressed. I am not sure where I am going wrong so any help is greatly appreciated. Code as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Question']))
    {
        $menuVar = $_POST['fontFamily'];
    }
?>

<p id="info-req">How did you find about this site?</p>

<form name="TestMenu" method="post" id="marketing">
    <select name="Question">
        <option <?php if($menuVar=="----------") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="----------">----------</option>
        <option <?php if($menuVar=="WebSearch") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="WebSearch">Web Search</option>
        <option <?php if($menuVar=="SocialMedia") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="SocialMedia">Social Media</option>
        <option <?php if($menuVar=="Wordofmouth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Wordofmouth">Word of mouth</option>
        <option <?php if($menuVar=="Other") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean `sticky`? Do you want the form to retain the previously selected value after the page has been refreshed?

Comment: There are other form fields on the page that are necessary and if no date is entered an error message will display. I do not want this drop menu to reset when this happens. I have solved the other form fields and they are no longer clearing but do not know how to keep the drop menu entry? If an error message is displayed because an invalid entry I want all of the data to remain as it was before the submit button was pressed. Without this happening the user will have to re-fill out the whole form.

Comment: Hi 007. I just noticed your post now. The page with all content is very big and will not fit in a screen shot. Problem has been solved now further down the page. Thank you for you willingness to help me : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no `$POST['fontFamily']` variable in your form. Why are you trying to use it?
You should use `$_POST['Question']` in order to get this value.

So it should be:

```
 if (isset($_POST['Question']))
{
    $menuVar = $_POST['Question'];
}
```

Also you should init `$menuVar` if there's no `$POST` in order not to get a `Notice: Undefined variable $menuVar`. So in the end you code should be:

```
   if (isset($_POST['Question']))
    {
        $menuVar = $_POST['Question'];
    } else {
        $menuVar = "----------";
    }
```

Comment: Fixed! I completely missed the fontFamily bit! That was a mistake. I have spent hours trying to work this out to no avail and was about to just give up! Thank you so much for your time and code. I will give back to the community with my photoshop skills as my coding skills are awful!

Comment: I recommend you to enable error_reporting including notices in PHP configuration on you development environment. Then you would be able to easily debug this issue.

Comment: Well when I did my initial php training I did set up locally and configured error reporting via terminal commands. Problem is after that I had some problem with apache that I just did not understand at all and installed MAMP. That is what I use now! Do you know a good PHP debugger? I definitely need one... I am self taught and really struggle when things are not working! Thank you for your help :  )

Comment: You don't need a debugger at this moment. You should just have set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` (you can also set it in PHP.ini which is available if you installed it on your own or via MAMP) and if needed just check variables values with `var_dump` in any place in your code to validate its value.

Comment: Ok sounds good. I will follow this advise and hope to be able to fix my own problems a bit more easily in the future! Thank you very much : )